# jsx styles did not accept variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this code within my loop

```
let widthStyle = obj.total_days * obj.calendayDay_width - 20

<div style={{
    width: widthStyle
}} />
```

it produce different result than this

```
<div style={{
    width: `${obj.total_days * obj.calendayDay_width - 20}`
}} />
```

I have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: What are the results? How do they differ?

Comment: `widthStyle` is a number. What inside `` is resolved to a string. That's the only difference I can say.

Comment: Both are invalid CSS anyway, unless the result is 0. There has to be a unit in the value.

Answer (score 0):

They will have the same effect, you are not specifying the width type eg `px` or `%`. append it at the end. Also you must make sure that the `obj` values are numbers

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
      var obj = {
            total_days: 20,
            calendayDay_width: 20
       }
       let widthStyle = obj.total_days * obj.calendayDay_width - 20
       return (
           <div>
              <div style={{width: `${obj.total_days * obj.calendayDay_width - 20}`+ 'px', backgroundColor: 'orange'
}} >Hello</div>
<div style={{
    width: widthStyle + 'px', backgroundColor: 'red'
}} >World</div>
           </div>
       )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```